# How to create two virtualenv with different python versions?

Tags: python, virtualenv, git-bash, python-venv, pyenv

I already have python 3.5.4 and 3.8.2 installed on my system.
I have been working on a project which required a virtual environment of python 3.5.4 but now I am creating a new project in which I have to use python v3.8.2 due to some dependencies.
Whenever I am trying to create a virtual environment in the new project it loads python 3.5.4

Also I used this command but did not work

```
$ "c:\Program Files\Python38\python" -m venv "c:\New Project\"
```

It did create an environment successfully but with python v3.5.4
What should I do ?

Comment: How do you know that it uses v3.5.4?

Comment: I don't kown if there is virtualenv (package) in windows. But in linux, you can easely create virtualenv with it, with any version of python, you just need to specify the python that will be used with parameter --python. Here is an egg : virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.odoo_08

Comment: @quamrana By running `python -V`

Comment: @m0r7y That doesn't help in Windows however the answer provided does work perfectly fine

Comment: But that just means python 3.5.4 is on your path and nothing to do with venv. Did you activate it?

Comment: @quamrana Yes, you need to activate the virtualenv and then run `python -V`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding both versions to your path, and using the latest version you added work?

usually when I create a virtual env, I:

- change my directory to the folder I want the env folder to be in
  (Ex. `C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Project`)
- run `$ python(version) -m venv (name_of_env_folder)`

Comment: This works ! Just to add to your answer to avoid confusion .. I run the command `"C:\\Program Files\python38\python" -m venv venv` .. venv is the name of my folder!